Google Driveフォルダ移動時のGASと機能の動作について
TOP階層ー第2階層 Aフォルダーaフォルダ内にGASや関数を含んだスプレッドシートがある場合 Bフォルダーaフォルダ内を移動した場合に既に作成しているGASや関数などは、修正が必要になりますか？ ドキュメントIDなどが変わりますか？
以上、ご教示のほどよろしくお願いいたします。
aフォルダ内をTOP階層のフォルダへ移動した場合に動作に問題が無いかご教示いただけますか。 アイテム数が40万までのためフォルダなどの細分化が必要になったが動作検証を行うユーザーが退職したため動作が分からない
